# puppet only sees internal dns name instead of hostname

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to puppetize an amazon EC2 host. I first made sure the puppet ssl directory was empty:

```
[root@web3:~] #ls -lh /var/lib/puppet/ssl/
total 0
```

Setup my hostname in /etc/hosts

```
[root@web3:~] #cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
10.0.2.101  web3.company.com web3
```

Gave the server the hostname I wanted and verified it:

```
[root@web3:~] #hostname web3
[root@web3:~] #hostname
web3
[root@web3:~] #hostname -f
web3.company.com
```

Yet when I run the puppet command to register it with the puppet server, it still comes up with the internal ec2 ip address instead of the hostname that I'm trying to give it:

```
[root@web3:~] #puppet agent --test --waitforcert 60 --server puppet.company.com
Info: Creating a new SSL key for ip-10-0-2-101.ec2.internal
Info: Caching certificate for ca
Info: Caching certificate_request for ip-10-0-2-101.ec2.internal
Info: Caching certificate for ca
```

What am I missing here? How can I get puppet to see the hostname that I want instead of the internal IP dns given by Amazon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these are the docs you are looking for http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html

**Disclaimer**
I've never used puppet and don't know what exactly its doing

Comment: I had to either rm the /etc/puppet.conf file or change the certname value to the name of the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the `certname` in the Puppet configuration file: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/config_file_main.html

For example, on your EC2 node, you could have a `puppet.conf` with the following ini formatted settings:

```
[main]
certname = web3.company.com
```

and that will specify the certificate name that you desire, as long as you are not overriding it in the `[master]` section..

Comment: @bluethundr You accidentally changed the accepted answer FYI.